# How to use a Spring bean as a Morphia entity listener?

Tags: spring, morphia

The [Morphia documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/guides/lifeCycleMethods/) provides an example on how `@EntityListeners` can be used to externalize life cycle methods to a separate class:

```
@EntityListeners(DigitalSigner.class)
public class BankAccount {
  @Id
  String id;
  Date lastUpdated = new Date();
}

class DigitalSigner {
  @PrePersist
  void prePersist(final Object entity, final DBObject dbObject) {
     dbObject.put("signature", sign(dbObject));
  }
}
```

However, the documentation doesn't state how the class is instantiated. My guess is by calling the no-args constructor.

I need to call a Spring service from the entity listener or have the Spring service work as the listener. How can this be achieved (preferably without sticking the service into a `static` field)?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality is provided by the [ObjectFactory](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/ObjectFactory.html) class, which can be set using [MapperOptions.setObjectFactory](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/mapping/MapperOptions.html#setObjectFactory-org.mongodb.morphia.ObjectFactory-). The custom ObjectFactory should return the appropriate Spring beans for the requested class types.